# How to Bulk Add Outro Video with ffmpeg?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-watermarking

I would like to add a short outro video to a list of videos or add a "watermark" that covers the entire video during the last 5 seconds. How can I achieve this? I added ffmpeg in the title but if there is another free way of doing it in bulk then I am all ears. My OS is Windows 10.

Thanks!

Comment: This is essentially two questions in one: 1) how to concat and/or overlay videos with `ffmpeg`?, and 2) how to implement this `ffmpeg` command in a batch script? Do you need help with both?

Comment: yes, I'd need help with both.